# traer el dato verdadero de una comparación entre listas python

Tags: lista, bucle-for, condiciones, python-2.7, else

El eje pedalier debe ubicarse entre 240 y 300 cm del piso.
Las bielas deben medir máximo 180 mm y mínimo 160 mm.
La longitud del sillín debe ser mínimo 240 mm y máximo 275mm
El manilar debe tener máximo 50 cm de ancho.
Por tal razón, le han encomendado a usted la selección de los diseños que cumplen con las condiciones del reglamento, así que debe construir el software que procesará los datos de las bases de datos donde reposan los diseños en el sistema. Su misión es crear un programa en Python que permita mostrarle a los equipos ciclísticos la lista de las bicicletas que cumplen con los requerimientos y por supuesto el valor de las mismas para su consideración.

datos de prueba:

3

270 165 275 40 1195

275 180 230 50 1045

225 180 225 55 1120

1195

```
def leer_datos():
  N= int(input())
  db=[N]
 
 for i in range(N):
  c=input().split()
  db.append(c)
 return db

pedalier_min=240 
pedalier_max=300

bielas_max=180   
bielas_min=160

sillin_min=240 
sillin_max=275

manilar=50

reglamentos = [pedalier_min,pedalier_max,bielas_max,bielas_min,sillin_max,sillin_min,manilar]

def analizar_datos(db, reglamentos):
 
 disponible= False
 
 valor_bici=[]
  
 
 for registro in range(db[0]):
   if(int(db[0]) >= reglamentos[0]) and\
     (int(db[0]) <= reglamentos[1]) and\
     (int(db[1]) <= reglamentos[2]) and\
     (int(db[1]) >= reglamentos[3]) and\
     (int(db[2]) >= reglamentos[4]) and\
     (int(db[2]) <= reglamentos[5]) and\
     (int(db[3]) <= reglamentos[6]):

     disponible=True
     valor_bici=registro[4]

  if not disponible:
    return "NO DISPONIBLE"
  else:
   return valor_bici


datos_leidos = leer_datos ()

resultado = analizar_datos(datos_leidos, reglamentos)

print(resultado)
```

siempre retorna disponible y no el valor de mas alto de la cicla que es  1195

no se que estoy haciendo mal, Ayudaaa

Answer (score 0):

bienvenida, he hecho algunos cambios en tu código para que funcione.
Para empezar vamos a ver que te piden: **que permita mostrarle a los equipos ciclísticos la lista de las bicicletas que cumplen con los requerimientos y por supuesto el valor de las mismas para su consideración.**, esto cambia tu enfoque de guardar el precio, debo guardar los datos de cada bici que cumpla con los requisitos.
Parto de la base de que el método **leer_datos**, te devuelve esto:

```
[
    [ 270, 165, 270, 40, 1195 ],
    [ 275, 180, 230, 50, 1045 ],
    [ 225, 180, 225, 55, 1120 ]
]
```

Primer modificación (es lo que daba problemas) la declaración de **reglamento**, tu pusiste esto:

```
reglamentos = [ pedalier_min, pedalier_max, bielas_max, bielas_min, sillin_max, sillin_min, manilar ]
```

y deberías poner esto:

```
reglamentos = [ pedalier_min, pedalier_max, bielas_max, bielas_min, sillin_min, sillin_max, manilar ]
```

la diferencia es sutil, están invertidas las posiciones de **sillin** eso hace que nunca entres en el if (también podrías invertir la comparación dentro de este).

```
def analizar_datos( db, reglamentos ):
    registro = []  
    for i in range( len( db )):
        if db[ i ][0] >= reglamentos[0] and db[ i ][0] <= reglamentos[1] and db[ i ][1] <= reglamentos[2] and db[ i ][1] >= reglamentos[3] and db[ i ][2] >= reglamentos[4] and db[ i ][2] <= reglamentos[5] and db[ i ][3] <= reglamentos[6]:
           registro.append( db[ i ] )
          
    return registro

def mostrar( res ):
    for i in range( len( res )):
        print( f"Puedes comprar la bicicleta {i} con pedalier de {res[ i ][ 0 ]} bielas de {res[ i ][ 1 ]} sillin de {res[ i ][ 2 ]} manillar de {res[ i ][ 3 ]} y con un precio de {res[ i ][ 4 ]}")

datos_leidos = leer_datos ()
resultado = analizar_datos( db, reglamentos )
print( mostrar( resultado ))
```

esto imprime:

"***Puedes comprar la bicicleta 0 con pedalier de 270 bielas de 165 sillin de 270 manillar de 40 y con un precio de 1195***"

Dentro de **analizar_datos**, creamos la lista **registros** donde almacenaremos los datos de la/las bicicletas que cumplan con el reglamento.
En el if modifiqué como le pides los datos a **db** que es una matriz, y limpié un poco para que fuera más legible, cuando las condiciones son satisfechas, agregamos a **registro** la lista correspondiente, y finalmente devolvemos la matriz que contiene todas las bicis que pasaron el filtro.

El método **mostrar**, itera sobre la matriz recibida el imprime el mensaje correspondiente, obviamente, es mi interpretación de como hacerlo, y queda a tu criterio como implementarlo.